# An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'pokemon_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, pokeapi

I'm a bit clueless.

I would like to import data to my DB.
This is a example entity:
[image: Entity]

all fields nesassary fields were filled, but doctrine tells me:

```
In ExceptionConverter.php line 111:

An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'pokemon_id' cannot be null

In Exception.php line 26:

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'pokemon_id' cannot be null


In Statement.php line 92:

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'pokemon_id' cannot be null
```

Here is the snipped of my entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private ?int $pokemonId;

public function getPokemonId(): ?int
{
    return $this->pokemonId;
}

public function setPokemonId(int $pokemonId): self
{
    $this->pokemonId = $pokemonId;

    return $this;
}
```

Where did i miss the point?

P.S.:

Maybe I should also tell that this property never can be null.
And I have a relation to an

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Pokemon\Pokemon", inversedBy="pokemon_id")
*/
private $pokemon;

public function getPokemon(): ?Pokemon
{
    return $this->pokemon;
}

public function setPokemon($pokemon): self
{
    $this->pokemon = $pokemon;

    return $this;
}
```

Why does SQL not take my property?

Comment: What code do you use to create & save these entities?

Comment: $this->em->contains($pokemonForm) ? $this->em->merge($pokemonForm) : $this->em->persist($pokemonForm);
        $this->em->flush();

Comment: In the orm column annotion, add 'nullable=true'

Comment: I should add that this property never can be null. 

Here is an example dataset. 

id,identifier,form_identifier,pokemon_id,introduced_in_version_group_id,is_default,is_battle_only,is_mega,form_order,order

1,bulbasaur,,1,1,1,0,0,1,1

There is something wrong in storing the data into the databse because my object holds the pokemonId value.

Comment: Maybe I found the issue. I gonna write later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

When you have a one to many relation (in my example the pokemon) you mustn't use `setpokemonId()` to store the relation, you use `setPokemon()` instead. Doctrine will store the value then in the pokemon_id column.